# Local Tile Cache in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

I was wondering if there is a way to load a local tile cache (ie: MB Tiles etc.) of imagery that is sitting locally into QGIS?  I am hoping to use some tablets for field verification and would like to have ortho imagery to assist with the verification.  Where I will be doing the field work I will not have wifi or cell coverage, so I will need local connections.  I am hoping to use tiles over source imagery to minimize the large storage requirements needed for the orthos, and to increase the performance on a tablet.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quiet a Tile Cache, but I use my self-rendered Openstreetmap tiles, as well as tiled versions of german and dutch topo maps with the openlayers plugin in QGIS.

To serve the tiles, I have set up a local apache server, and modified the preset urls in the plugin to `http://localhost/path/to/tile/folders/...`

Answer (score 4):

QGIS uses GDAL for it's raster I/O. The MBTiles format is supported from GDAL 1.10:

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html

If the version of QGIS you're using has been built against 1.10 or above, it should support MBTiles out of the box.